# failsafe mysql query insert with verifying value in other table

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have 2 tables: `dbvotes.votes` and `dbsystem.topics`
Now I want to be sure that if someone votes for a topic. the query "checks" if the topic exists. I have the following (thanks to some topics on SO).

**This code works but is it the right way?**

```
INSERT INTO dbvotes.votes (topicid,vote,voterid) VALUES(
(SELECT topicid 
 FROM dbsystem.topics 
 WHERE topicid = 20),
(12),
(1)
)
```

The part where it uses a select on a different database.table is my fail safe (because it returns Null/mysqlerror when a topicid doesn't exist). The values used are user submitted.

Is this the proper way to nest sql queries in the "values" part of an insert clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Instead of trying to ensure data integrity via code, you should define foreign key constraints which do the job for you. In your case, `dbvotes.votes` would reference `dbsystem.topics`, which means, that you can't insert into votes, when there's no corresponding topic. By the way, the names suggest, that they are in different databases. Do you have a special reason for this? It's sort of "unusual" and I wouldn't recommend it.

Anyway, your table definition would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE votes(
id int auto_increment,
topicid int,
vote tinyint,
voterid int,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (fk_topicid_topics) REFERENCES topics(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You can also add options like

```
...
FOREIGN KEY (fk_topicid_topics) REFERENCES topics(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

which means, that the votes get deleted when the corresponding topic is deleted.

For this to work you have to use an Engine that supports foreign keys, meaning **not** MyISAM but most likely InnoDB.
And you have to have an index on the referenced column.

Finally your insert statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO votes(topicid,vote,voterid)
VALUES (20, 12, 1);
```

Comment: wow that is superb!! thank you very much. Can I do a cascade also when a user is deleted or does that require magic? I use 2 databases indeed. The reason is that I'm trying to create some sort of voting functionality without having to mess in the database of the original system. So the user can only select values from the system database. Does the foreign key than still work?

Comment: I think so, yes. And for the "user deleted" thing just create another foreign key to users table. Also, just a hint, you can grant read only access to single tables also, even for columns. No need to keep it in two databases, but it should work anyway.

Comment: thanks a lot for the heads up, this seems like the best solution! cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could use this :

```
INSERT INTO dbvotes.votes (topicid,vote,voterid) 
SELECT (20, 12, 1)
FROM  dbsystem.topics
WHERE topicid = 20;
```

If a `topic` with `topicid` equal to `20` exists in the table `dbsystem.topics`, the INSERT will occur with the values `(20, 12, 1)`. Otherwise, there will be no INSERT.